# partition key in cassandra, make field invisible

Tags: database, cassandra, partitioning

I consider partition key in cassandra. My choice is timestamp. I think that it is fairly Ok for performance. I am made to duplicate this column because I would like to be able to do comparison `>` and `>=`.
Is it possible to make invisible some column in cassandra?
Maybe, other field is better chocie of key partitioning ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp is almost always the wrong partitioning key. See https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling but basically you should have your partition key the object your looking up and use timestamp as the clustering key that you can then do the `>` and `>=` on.

Comment: should have your partition key the object your looking up - can you say it in other words, please ?

Comment: Whatever it is that you have a time series for. For example if what you are storing is temp readings from a device, use the device id or station id for the partition key. There needs to be some partitioning, if its "all things" consider using the year/month/day as the key so that way it breaks up the data but still is querably. A partition has to be able to exist on a single node so it cannot be too huge, but you also cannot query across partitions easily (unless you use spark, but then its a lot slower).